# When are threads created when calling async functions of boost.asio?

Tags: c++, boost

I am quite new to the boost.asio library, so please forgive me if I understand the library wrongly.
I understand that when asynchronous functions are called, they are run in background threads. My question is, when are the background threads created? Before or when I call async functions?
I ask this because I am afraid creating threads upon async operations are called will incur unnecessary overhead (I know the overhead is on the microsecond level, but it is important for my application). I did quite thorough search and am still now clear about it.
It seems asio creates its own thread pool to achieve asynchronicity, so chance is a thread in the thread pool may be reused when an async function is called. Is there any guarantee that this is always true? If not, are there any params that I can tune to force thread pool preallocation and no more thread creation thereafter?
Thanks!

Comment: I think the whole point of asyncio is that new threads are *not* created. It's essentially a co-operative yield system.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please provide any reference to the mechanism of boost.asio? I am a bit surprised by your comment. Suppose I want to send 1gb data over tcp socket, so I call async_write function. The write should take quite long. If no thread is created, how is sending data done in the end?

Comment: on posix systems, asio will use sockets in non-blocking mode and the io_context's run-loop will block on a call to select/epoll/poll (depending on exact OS). The OS will allow this function to return when one of the relevant descriptors has data available, an error and/or is able to write more data. Asio takes care of all of this under the covers for you.
https://linux.die.net/man/2/select
Windows behaves similarly but uses windows-specific calls.

Comment: [The Proactor design Pattern: Concurrency Without Threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) describes how `boost::asio` implements concurrency. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwOv_tw2eA4 explains it very nicely.

Comment: Learned a lot, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that when asynchronous functions are called, they are run in background threads.

This *may* happen as part of the specific implementation detail of the io_object against which you invoked an asynchronous call. It is by no means guaranteed. If the object is able to achieve its goals without creating a thread or putting work on a thread queue, you can be sure that it will have been written that way.

> My question is, when are the background threads created?

Asio io objects are handles. They defer to a service object to perform their work. The service object is created once and attached to the io_context on *first use*. This is most likely where any threads or background thread-pools would be created. It is a one-off operation because the io_service remains active for the lifetime of the io_context.

> Before or when I call async functions?

^^ therefore, before.

> I ask this because I am afraid creating threads upon async operations are called will incur unnecessary overhead (I know the overhead is on the microsecond level, but it is important for my application).

Not a concern

> I did quite thorough search and am still now clear about it. It seems asio creates its own thread pool to achieve asynchronicity, so chance is a thread in the thread pool may be reused when an async function is called. Is there any guarantee that this is always true?

This is absolutely an implementation detail, and changes depending on the underlying OS.

> If not, are there any params that I can tune to force thread pool preallocation and no more thread creation thereafter?

In general, the control you have is in determining how many threads you allow to service the io_context. There may be ways of controlling the underlying implementation, you'd have to check the source code/documentation of asio to see how it creates an async environment on your specific OS.

It is likely to be as efficient as possible. I wouldn't worry unduly that too many threads will be created, or that they will be created and destroyed often.